# Array sort, slice and reverse returns empty

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array sorted by the last column, where I want to use/show the top 3 sorted rows.

Slicing works and reversing the 2nd dimension (2nd example) works as well. 
However when I want to reverse the 1st dimension (3rd example) I get an empty print out.

I replicated [these](http://structure.usc.edu/numarray/node26.html) examples but when I enter a slice and a -1 for reverse I get an empty output as well.

It's probably really obvious what I'm missing...

```
arr = np.array ([[8, 2, 4, 6],
                 [8, 3, 1, 8],
                 [3, 7, 6, 1],
                 [9, 4, 2, 4],
                 [4, 7, 5, 8],
                 [1, 9, 3, 5],
                 [1, 3, 9, 111],
                 [3, 6, 7, 111],
                 [2, 8, 2, 111],
                 [4, 5, 9, 3]])

print(arr[0:10,:])
print("###")

# Sort by column 4, then by column 3
lexsorted_index = np.lexsort((arr[:, 2], arr[:, 3])) 
a = arr[lexsorted_index]

print(a[0:10:1,::]) #0-10th row each step, all columns
print("###")
print(a[0:10:1,::-1]) #0-10th row each step, all columns reversed

print("###")
print(a[0:3:-1,::]) #0-3rd row reversed, all columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python slice syntax is `start:stop:step`, not `low:high:step`. If your step is counting down, the start is the high endpoint, not the low endpoint.

Also, slices are start-inclusive and stop-exclusive, not low-inclusive and high-exclusive, so if you want the first 3 rows, your start value should be 2 instead of 3, and your stop value should just be omitted to slice as far as it can go (because -1 doesn't mean what you want).

```
print(a[2::-1])
```